# Is it possible to generate a list from a datatype's possible values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, list-comprehension

Can a list be generated from a type's possible values? E.g.

`data Shape = Circle | Rectangle | Triangle | Pentagon`

to

`[Circle,Rectangle,Triangle,Pentagon]`

Comment: Yep it's a duplicate. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it can. It's a duty of [Enum](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Prelude.html#t:Enum) and [Bounded](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) type classes e.g.

```
λ data Shape = Circle | Rectangle | Triangle | Pentagon deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)
λ [minBound .. maxBound] :: [Shape]
[Circle,Rectangle,Triangle,Pentagon]
λ [minBound ..] :: [Shape]
[Circle,Rectangle,Triangle,Pentagon]
```